# How to prolong the session duration in Spring Webflow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflow, spring-session

> As long as I know the duration of the default session is 30 mins and I
>   wanna change this for my specific flow that I created using Spring
>   Webflow? My question is How can i achieve this?

**I have researched and found some interesting articles and solutions but none of them seems to work for me and also their solution not straightforward**

> To change a single request's session we should set HttpSession's setMaxInactiveInterval right? So if it is, How and Where I should set it? IN SPRING WEBFLOW?

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to the raw `HttpSession` in Web Flow, you need to use the `ExternalContext`. Like this:

```java
((HttpServletRequest)
 RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getExternalContext()
                     .getNativeRequest())
    .getSession())
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/context/ExternalContext.html#getNativeRequest--